# How to calculate the difference of two values of the same column and add a new column with the results

Tags: pandas, apply

In Excel Column A with Values[1,2,4,4,5,5]. The answer would be with a new column B: B2 = A2-A1= 1, B3=A3-A2=2, B4=A4-A3=0 I don't mind getting 0 for the first row of the new column

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[6,2,4,5], 'b':[3,4,8,7]})

#Columnn c based off b 
df['c] = [0,1,4,-1]

# The first value is a zero by default in the new column
```

Doesn't work

```py
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.d[n+1] - x.d[n], axis=1)
```

```py
#Columnn c based off b from above
df['c] = [0,1,4,-1]

# The first value is a zero by default in the new column
```

Comment: df['c']=df.b.diff().fillna(0)